# How to correctly use a curried selector function with react-redux's useSelector hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am using react-redux with hooks, and I need a selector that takes a parameter that is not a prop.  The [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) states

> The selector function does not receive an ownProps argument. However,
>   props can be used through closure (see the examples below) or by using
>   a curried selector.

However, they don't provide an example.  What is the proper way to curry as described in the docs?

This is what I've done and it seems to work, but is this right? Are there implications from returning a function from the `useSelector` function (it seems like it would never re-render?)

```
// selectors
export const getTodoById = state => id => {
  let t = state.todo.byId[id];
  // add display name to todo object
  return { ...t, display: getFancyDisplayName(t) };
};

const getFancyDisplayName = t => `${t.id}: ${t.title}`;

// example component
const TodoComponent = () => {
   // get id from react-router in URL
   const id = match.params.id && decodeURIComponent(match.params.id);

   const todo = useSelector(getTodoById)(id);

   return <span>todo.display</span>;
}
```

Comment: It's a good question, can't find any example as well, but you can still use `connect` which receives `ownProps`. Or you could reverse the currying (e.g. `id => state => state.todo.byId[id]` and then `useSelector(getTodoById(id))`.

Comment: Or just call it directly yourself: `useSelector(state => getTodoById(state)(id));` that way, the return value is taken into account in the hook and should re-render accordingly.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I'd like to understand your second comment better.  doesn't useSelector just do an equality compare to see if changed, how does this work for your function?

Comment: `useSelector` subscribes to the store, and because your `getTodoById` always returns a new function, I think your component will always be re-rendered.

Comment: After testing it, I wrote an answer to highlight the problems of `useSelector(getTodoById)(id)`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When the return value of a selector is a new function, **the component will always re-render on each store change.**

> `useSelector()` uses strict `===` reference equality checks by default, not shallow equality

You can verify this with a super simple selector:

```
const curriedSelector = state => () => 0;

let renders = 0;
const Component = () => {
  // Returns a new function each time
  // triggers a new render each time
  const value = useSelector(curriedSelector)();
  return `Value ${value} (render: ${++renders})`;
}
```

Even if the `value` is always `0`, the component will re-render on each store action since *`useSelector` is unaware that we're calling the function* to get the real value.

But if we make sure that `useSelector` receives the final `value` instead of the function, then the component only gets rendered on real `value` change.

```
const curriedSelector = state => () => 0;

let renders = 0;
const Component = () => {
  // Returns a computed value
  // triggers a new render only if the value changed
  const value = useSelector(state => curriedSelector(state)());
  return `Value ${value} (render: ${++renders})`;
}
```

---

Conclusion is that it works, but it's **super inefficient to return a new function (or any new non-[primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures))** from a selector used with `useSelector` each time it is called.

> props can be used through closure (see the examples below) or by using a curried selector.

The documentation meant either:

- closure `useSelector(state => state.todos[props.id])`
- curried `useSelector(state => curriedSelector(state)(props.id))`

[`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapstatetoprops-state-ownprops-object) is always available, and if you changed your selector a little, it could work with both.

```
export const getTodoById = (state, { id }) => /* */

const Component =  props => {
  const todo = useSelector(state => getTodoById(state, props));
}
// or
connect(getTodoById)(Component)
```

---

Note that since you're returning an Object from your selector, you might want to change the default equality check of `useSelector` to a [shallow equality check](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#recipe-useshallowequalselector).

> ```
> import { shallowEqual } from 'react-redux'
>
> export function useShallowEqualSelector(selector) {
>   return useSelector(selector, shallowEqual)
> }
> ```

or just

```
const todo = useSelector(state => getTodoById(state, id), shallowEqual);
```

If you're performing costly computations in the selector or the data is deeply nested and performance becomes a problem, take a look at [Olivier's answer which uses memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465617/1218980).

Comment: seems like, for my case, you would not even need currying then and could just pass state and arguments as parameters? `useSelector(state  => getTodoWithDisplay(state, id))`

Comment: @user210757 I updated my answer with a common form for selector that works with both `connect` and `useSelector`.

Comment: @user210757 but yes, you're right, you could directly pass the `id` if you want!

Comment: if he returns a `new object` in the `getTodoById` function, the component will gets re-rendered on each store change

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I now address that with `shallowEqual`, as per the doc.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Redux and React use shallow equal all over the place, if performance becomes a problem, there are other solution, like memoization, but in this case, it's overkill and irrelevant to the problem OP was asking about.

Comment: @EmileBergeron - Per your rollback, my changes were because "super inefficient to pass a new function each time to useSelector" doesn't make sense, you always pass a function to useSelector, i.e `state => state.byId[id]`. The problem is returning a function from useSelector's selector function argument, rather than a value. That was what my change to your answer was attempting to clarify.

Comment: @user210757 passing **a new function each time** is inefficient but yeah, I understand the confusion between the return value and the selector itself. I could change it to focus on the return value instead.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution, it uses **memoïzation** to not re-render the component on each store change :

First I create a function to make selectors, because the selector depends on the component property `id`, so I want to have a **new selector per component instances**.

The selector will prevent the component to re-render when the todo or the id prop hasn't changed.

Lastly I use `useMemo` because  I don't want to have **more than one selector per component instance**.

You can see the [last example of the documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors) to have more information

```
// selectors
const makeGetTodoByIdSelector = () => createSelector(
   state => state.todo.byId,
   (_, id) => id,
   (todoById, id) => ({
       ...todoById[id], 
       display: getFancyDisplayName(todoById[id])
   })
);

const getFancyDisplayName = t => `${t.id}: ${t.title}`;

// example component
const TodoComponent = () => {
  // get id from react-router in URL
  const id = match.params.id && decodeURIComponent(match.params.id);

  const getTodoByIdSelector = useMemo(makeGetTodoByIdSelector, []);

  const todo = useSelector(state => getTodoByIdSelector(state, id));

  return <span>todo.display</span>;
}
```

Comment: Your initial answer wasn't adding anything new, but now that you've added Memoization and that it differs from other answers, I removed my downvote and added a link to your answer in my own.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is how it's done, simplified example:

```js
// Curried functions
const getStateById = state => id => state.todo.byId[id];

const getIdByState = id => state => state.todo.byId[id];

const SOME_ID = 42;

const TodoComponent = () => {
  // id from API
  const id = SOME_ID;

  // Curried
  const todoCurried = useSelector(getStateById)(id);
  const todoCurried2 = useSelector(getIdByState(id));

  // Closure
  const todoClosure = useSelector(state => state.todo.byId[id]);

  // Curried + Closure
  const todoNormal = useSelector(state => getStateById(state)(id));

  return (
    <>
      <span>{todoCurried.display}</span>
      <span>{todoCurried2.display}</span>
      <span>{todoClosure.display}</span>
      <span>{todoNormal.display}</span>
    </>
  );
};
```

Full example:

[image: Edit styled-antd-react-starter]

Comment: Thanks, I know it's just an example, but the closure example doesn't work for me because what I am doing is deriving data on the fly - the data comes back from the api and is stored in the reducer (without display field), and I want the selector to get one "todo" and have derived "display" added to it.

Comment: I found after upvoting this answer that it is partly correct and incomplete. Mostly, the 
constant re-rendering caused by the curried selector `useSelector(getStateById)(id)` and the strict equal that won't work when returning a new object each time. Be careful!

Answer (score 1):

This is helper-hook `useParamSelector` for **TypeScript**, which implements the official approach of Redux Toolkit.

Hook implementation:

```
// Define types and create new hook 
export type ParametrizedSelector<A, R> = (state: AppState, arg: A) => R;
export const proxyParam: <T>(_: AppState, param: T) => T = (_, param) => param;
export function useParamSelector<A, R>(
  selectorCreator: () => ParametrizedSelector<A, R>,
  argument: A,
  equalityFn: (left: R, right: R) => boolean = shallowEqual
): R {
  const memoizedSelector = useMemo(() => {
    const parametrizedSelector = selectorCreator();
    return (state: AppState) => parametrizedSelector(state, argument);
  }, [typeof argument === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(argument) : argument]);
  return useSelector(memoizedSelector, equalityFn);
}
```

Create parametrized selector:

```
export const selectUserById = (): ParametrizedSelector<string, User> =>
  createSelector(proxyParam, selectAllUsers, (id, users) => users.find((it) => it.id === id));
```

And use it:

```
const user = useParamSelector(selectUserById, 1001); // in components
const user = selectUserById()(getState(), 1001); // in thunks
```

You can also use it hook with selectors created with reselect's `createSelector`.

Comment: Thank you for share! It looks like you wanted to write it like below as `filter` returns an array:
 `export const selectUserById = (): ParametrizedSelector<string, User | undefined> =>
  createSelector(proxyParam, selectAllUsers, (id, users) => users.find((it) => it.id === id));`